# Attic HVAC ducts are in the way. What should I do?

Tags: attic, ducts

Just moved in to a new house back in September and I want to add some pendant lights in the kitchen. Went up into the attic and looked around...

The main HVAC duct bisects the attic and I will have to find a way to physically move my person over / under it in order to get where I need to go.

Is there a common method for dealing with this? Can I disconnect it from the main air handler and reconnect it after I finish running the wires? A leap of faith across this giant duct will end up with me falling through the ceiling. Any solution is appreciated

[image: Attic ducts]

Comment: Is it the wires or your body that you need to get around the duct? It’s unclear what you’re asking. You can just staple wires to the framing?

Comment: For walking/standing/climbing over you use something to hold your weight.  2x6s or 2x8s(or similar) across a few of bottom trusses, maybe four or six feet long.

Comment: Hey! I need to physically go to the other side of the attic and it is blocked by the duct. Once there I will be pulling / stapling wires. The duct runs pretty much the entire length of the attic and I need to go across it (it's like a river in my way... kinda...) Hope that helps clarify!

Comment: @crip659 - there is about 1-1/2 feet of blowing in insulation beneath that duct. The duct itself is probably about 3' off the bottom truss and it is about 18" around. I've seen people build boxes around these ducts but I'm curious if there is an easier way to get across it

Comment: *Blown in insulation

Comment: Rather than risk putting your foot through the ceiling and getting injured, I would construct "cat walks" through the attic area. I would also install some lighting.  You could put the cat-walks up on risers to be tall enough to run clear over the insulation.